# Amazon EC2 Tomcat does not support restful service?

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've a local project with Eclipse + Tomcat setup. My restful services is working.

However, when I deploy over to EC2's Tomcat server, I can still view the web pages, but the restful services is not working.

Any idea why?

Comment: What port are you running the rest service on?

Comment: 8080 on EC2, does port matters?

Comment: Yes, port matters. Have you made sure that your security group allows traffic over port 8080 as well as 80?

Comment: yes, my security group allow traffic at both port.

Comment: Can you post your Tomcat Config?

Comment: You say your "services [are] not working"? What happens when you try to access them? Connection failure? 404 response? 500 response? No response? Client hang? Server hang?